# How to load related objects in JSON column

Tags: ef-core-8.0

I save owned object as JSON column using `ToJson()`, this object contains navigation properties to other entities.

EF Core throws an exception as `.Include()` works only with entities.

Is there are any way to load entities in the same query?

```
entity.OwnsOne(x => x.CrDetail, nav =>
{
    nav.ToJson("Address");
    nav.OwnsOne(x => x.NationalAddress, nanav =>
    {
        nanav.Navigation(x => x.City).AutoInclude();     // Exception as not owner
        nanav.Property(x => x.District);                 // Exception as owned by non-owner
        nanav.Ignore(x => x.UnitType);
    });
})
```

Comment: If you are adding navigation properties in your JSON then you are doing things wrong.

Comment: @DavidG Actually I ignore all navigation properties as it's not acceptable by the ef but I need them loaded during get details.